# Keynote Master Slide Text Box Placeholder Relative Position

Tags: keynote

I have a Keynote Master Slide set, where I have two text box placeholders with two different text styles, see picture, "Name" and "Date" (a date span).

[image]

The `Name` textbox could have content wrapping to multiple lines. In that case, I would like the `Date` to *continue* to stay 8 pixels below the `Name` textbox. Right now, the `Name` box will overflow the `Date` box.

[image]

How can I achieve the `Date` textbox stay *n* pixels below `Name`?

Comment: Do you explicitly need two text boxes?

Comment: @Gummibando Yes, there's a need for different formatting and it's repeating. So I want to keep this consistent across the presentation.

Comment: You can achieve different text formatting via text styles within the same text box. Is there an explicit reason that the date range has to be in its own text box?

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'm still looking for somehow to fix the distance between two objects / text boxes though :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

You can achieve a similar result by putting both text elements into a single text (placeholder) box, then define different paragraph styles for "Name" and "date range" with the desired spacing before or after the paragraph in the "Format > Text > Spacing" sidebar.

[image]